# No buffer space available and tuning with sysctl

Tags: linux, ubuntu-12.04, snmp, sysctl

Not really a network guy so please bear with me.

I'm currently hosting a web application that sends UDP to all IP addresses in it's subnet periodically. That's 2048 IPs. My problem is it throws `No buffer space available` after sometime.

I adjusted some values using `sysctl` namely:

- `net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh1 = 2048`
- `net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh2 = 4096`
- `net.ipv4.neigh.default.gc_thresh3 = 8192`

And it worked, but severely slows down the response time of the server. It's written in `Java` and running in a [fit-pc2](http://www.fit-pc.com/web/fit-pc/fit-pc2-specifications/) (1.1ghz, 1gb of RAM, SD card) Oh the horror.

Given the limited resources, how do I optimize the server/kernel parameters to address the `No buffer space available` problem?

Answer (score 2):

It's not the sysctl setting as such, your server is slowing down as it has to continuously scan through an arp table with 2k entries.

Things worth trying are:

- increasing the default "arp cache timeout" from 60s to 3600s. This will lower the average arp-request rate from 34 req / s to 0.5 req / s.
- adding all interesting MAC addresses statically to the arp table

However, your best option is to separate your server from the 2k hosts by a router.

- If you can change the IP from your server just put it in another subnet
- If you can't change the IP you can split a /30 subnet of the /21 subnet and use a proxy-arp feature to glue them

Comment: Hey, thanks for the explanation and tips. I'll try those out. But it's rather interesting to point out that I've enabled `net.ipv4.conf.all.arp_filter` after reading http://www.austintek.com/LVS/LVS-HOWTO/HOWTO/LVS-HOWTO.arp_problem.html and the issue seems to go away. I will have to do more research. Excuse my ignorance.